# how to say "etc" in a subject

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, expression-choice, legalese

I am translating some legal certificate and I need to indicate that a construction method and related factors are in accordance with a law.

I am not sure what is the appropriate way to describe “related factors” in the sentence that is in. I tried “the like” as below, but not sure if this can be part of the subject.

“Method A and the likes are in accordance with the lawB”

It will be most appreciated if you could help me with this. Thank you in advance.

NOTE: contents of the “related factors” are not provided to me neither, so I need to be vague on that.

Comment: Why don't you want to use "and related factors", as you have in the question here?

Comment: You never want to be vague when it's anything legal.  You can be all-encompassing, but never vague.

Comment: You really ought to ask this question on a site for lawyers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera

Comment: If you use a vague phrase like that in a legal document you are handing lawyers a blank cheque.  They will argue till the cows come home over what is or isn't a related factor.

Comment: I think the real question here is: **what is the actual legal sense of the term you have translated as "related factors" in the original?** As @Chenmurka says, lawyers would never use such a vague term as "related factors". If we knew the answer to that, we might be able to help you. Does it mean something like **"similar methods"** or something like **"associated procedures"** or something else? We can't tell!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to define a distinct set of method, which includes 'Method A' and any others like it. If you can derive them from a common ancestor, that would provide you with the necessary bounds for something as necessarily specific as a legal document.

Something along the lines of

> "Method A, and any other methods :
>
> - derived from Method X
> - leveraging Method Y
> - optimised from Method Z
>
> are in accordance with Law B".

should suffice.

Comment: No, he is trying to translate a legal document which has a term in the original language that vaguely translates to English as "***related factors***". If we knew what that term actually meant to lawyers, we might be able to help him.

Comment: Oh - that's more clear, thank you. In that case, yes, this calls for some mind-reading of the original authors. As a software developer I'm frequently expected to perform this feat but unfortunately it is far less possible than many people seem to realise...